# TextWatcher get loop when type a character in afterTextChanged() method

Tags: android

I have an EditText and I want to when a user typed a non-digit character except `,` the edittext delete that character `.` for example I want editText to accept text like this: 5451,56589,7545
and when the user typed a non-digit character like 454d54 the "d" character was deleted and just 45454 stay in the edittext.
my code is like this :

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),editable.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            editTextChecker(editable);
        }
    });

private void editTextChecker(Editable editable){
    String st=editable.toString();
    String regex="[\\D&&[^,]]";
    Pattern p=Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m=p.matcher(st);
    String retSt=st;
    if (st.length()>0) {
        if (m.find()) {
            retSt = m.replaceAll("");
        }
        editable.replace(0, st.length(), retSt);
    }
}
```

but when I type a digit character textWatcher gets infinite loop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change your method like this

```
private void editTextChecker(Editable editable) {
    String st = editable.toString();
    String regex = "[\\D&&[^,]]";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(st);
    String retSt = st;
    if (st.length() > 0 && m.find()) {
        retSt = m.replaceAll("");
        editable.replace(0, st.length(), retSt);
    }
}
```

It was calling afterTextChanged every time when there is a number so it was resulting in infinite loop hence change the condition

Answer (score 3):

You can set digits xml attribute like as below to accept only numbers and ',' for that edit text

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/myNumber"
android:digits="0123456789,"
/>
```

Comment: thanks in this case it is very good and work for me , but if i want to control what user is type in another case like split numbers with ";" or when i dont want to user can not type some character what i am doing ?

Comment: If you know what characters should be allowed to that edit text you can specify them in digits attribute. If you want a special pattern you can use regex check for that edit text.

Comment: yes, tanks it is good idea and its working , but just not setting inputType.